# Dumping PHP echo in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm loading images (pinpoints) onto a map and if you click on them they load a video URL in a DB. When I load the images using PHP I name their IDs the corresponding index in the MySQL so I can talk to them when I click on the images and attach an action to it, to load the correct video URL.

For some reason the PHP breaks the code.

```
<div id="satmap-div">
                    <div>
                        <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM btring_content";
                            $n = 1;

                            $result = $objCon->query($sql) or die('error in query:' . mysqli_error($objCon));

                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "<img id=" . $row['id'] .  " class='pinpoint' src='img/pp.png'/>";
                        ?>


                        <script>
                            $( "#satmap-div .pinpoint:nth-child(" + ( <?php echo (string)$n?> ) + ")" ).css( { "left": <?php echo (string)$row['leftPos']?>, "top": <?php echo (string)$row['topPos']?> } );
                        </script>

                        <?php
                            $n++;
                            }
                        ?>
</div>

        <img id="satmap" src="img/bigmap.gif"/>


                </div>

$('#satmap-div > div').children('img').click(function() {
                        var index = $(this).attr('id');
                        <?php 
                            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `btring_content` WHERE      `id`=18";
                            $result2 = $objCon->query($sql2) or die('error in query:' . mysqli_error($objCon));
                            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
                        ?>
                        $( "p" ).text( <?php echo (string)$row2['link']?> );
                   });
```

Comment: displaying any errors?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: can you post the html output after you run the script?

Comment: can you please add a copy of the .css() function who have between the script tags. Because I think you are closing the quotes incorrectly..

Comment: It's not displaying any errors.

Comment: Your image ID is not wrapped in quotes

Comment: Your while loop is also not closed, That's probably what's doing it

Comment: The while loop is closed right at where it says $n++. Wrapped the image ID in quotes. Doesn't resolve my problem though. Problem being that at the last part the echo doesn't do anything. Doesn't work with text(), alert or var_dump.

Comment: I'm not sure you can close it like that? If you are sure ignore me, but if not, remove the <?php's and warp the non php in an echo. If it works you can't do it like that.

Comment: @user2656265 put it in qoutes .text( "<?php echo (string)$row2['link']?> ");

Comment: @JoeSwindell You can close tags like that.

Comment: @KevinVoorn cool. Just seems weird to me.

Comment: I'm confident it works. It displays the correct results and the site doesn't die nor does it display any errors. - I just need the script to echo the URL from $row2 in the last part but it's not.

Comment: @wayzz You're a hero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
$( "p" ).text( <?php echo (string)$row2['link']?> );
```

to

```
$( "p" ).text( "<?php echo (string)$row2['link']?>" );
```

When displaying strings using the `.text()` function always qoute.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the following line in your code:

```
echo "<img id=" . $row['id'] .  " class='pinpoint' src='img/pp.png'/>";
```

This actually means your code will render as following:

```
<img id=3 class='pinpoint' src='img/pp.png'/>
```

As you can see, you are missing the quotes around `id`. Try using the following code instead:

```
echo "<img id='" . $row['id'] . "' class='pinpoint' src='img/pp.png'/>";
```

Further, your `<script>` is also missing `;` in the PHP echo statements:

```
<script>
        $( "#satmap-div .pinpoint:nth-child(" + ( <?php echo (string)$n?> ) + ")" ).css( { "left": <?php echo (string)$row['leftPos']?>, "top": <?php echo (string)$row['topPos']?> } );
    </script>
```

Change it to:

```
<script>
        $( "#satmap-div .pinpoint:nth-child(" + ( <?php echo (string)$n?> ) + ")" ).css( { "left": <?php echo (string)$row['leftPos']; ?>, "top": <?php echo (string)$row['topPos']; ?> } );
    </script>
```

Comment: Edit: I see Joe Swindell also pointed this out in the comments already.

Comment: afaik, quotes aren't needed if value is pure integer. Not sure though. I always you double quotes in html.

Comment: I think strictly speaking this works but for good practice we use qoutes

Comment: @Forien I always use double quotes as well, single in Javascript. It might work, but the code is a mess anyway so it's best practice to always use quotes.